# Hashing identity numbers in a XML-file using XSLT-2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a large XML file containing person data. I need to be able to output the `sourcedid/id` field hashed, using MD5 or similar.

Since the `sourcedid/id` field is going to be used as a unique identificator in a DB, the output string must be the same every time this process run for a specific number.

For example, using MD5, then the output from 123456789 will be `25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b` every time.

The XSL conversion will run on a Saxon 2.0 XSL processor. Any ideas?

Example input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>    <!-- Added by edit -->
    <person recstatus="1">
        <sourcedid>
            <source>SOFTWARE</source>
            <id>123456789</id>
        </sourcedid>
    </person>
    <person recstatus="1">  
        <sourcedid>
            <source>SOFTWARE</source>
            <id>987654321</id>
        </sourcedid>
    </person>
</root>   <!-- Added by edit -->
```

Expected output:

```
<person recstatus="1">
<sourcedid>
<source>SOFTWARE</source>
<id>25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b</id>
</sourcedid>
</person>
<person recstatus="1">  
<sourcedid>
<source>SOFTWARE</source>
<id>6ebe76c9fb411be97b3b0d48b791a7c9</id>
</sourcedid>
</person>
etc
```

Comment: So essentially you need an XSLT-2.0 implementation of the MD5 algorithm (or another hash algorithm)? Is that right?

Comment: I think both the Java platform and the .NET platform (for instance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5?view=netframework-4.8) offer ways to compute an MD5 hash so you can set up an extension function in Java or .NET that you can then call from XSLT in Saxon. See http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/ for details.

Comment: @zx485: Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Xalan instead.

You can just write your java class that does the hashing then you can call it from XSLT using xalan extensions.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   id="hash-function"
   version="1.0"
   xmlns="urn:com:xslt-hashData"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
   xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
   xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
   xmlns:decryption="xalan://com.eddo.sec.HashClass"
   extension-element-prefixes="java hashit"
>

  <xalan:component prefix="hashit"
                   elements=" " functions="doHash">
    <xalan:script lang="javaclass" src="xalan://com.eddo.sec.HashClass"/>
  </xalan:component>

   <xsl:template name="hashData">
      <xsl:param name="inData" />
    <xsl:value-of select="hashit:doHash($inEncData)" />


   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then call the template from your XSLT.

https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html